# What would be the most efficient way to select node for a content type?

Tags: 7, nodes

Right now i am using this query :

```
$query_info = db_query("SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE type=:type  AND language = :language AND status=1",
                array (':language'=> $language->language, ":type" => 'info_pages' , ))->fetchCol();
$info_pages = node_load_multiple($query_info);
```

As this site is going to have lots and lots of content I am wondering if this is the right way ? If not what would be a better approach ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
<?php
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
  ->fields('n', array('nid', 'title', 'status'))
  ->condition('type', 'info_page')
  ->addTag('node_access')
  ->execute();
while ($result = $query->fetch()) {
  print_r($result);
}
```

Query against node table must be a dynamic query with "node_access" tagging to prevent node access system by-passing.

Comment: See http://drupal.org/node/310075 and http://drupal.org/node/310077

Comment: Thanks for the input Sivaji, i checked both pages but i don't see anything about what you mentioned: preventing node access system by-passing. Can you elaborate please ?

Comment: The above links meant to help you with writing dynamic queries. For node access features in d7 see http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/group/node_access/7 Ref: "In node listings, the process above is followed except that hook_node_access() is not called on each node for performance reasons and for proper functioning of the pager system. When adding a node listing to your module, be sure to use a dynamic query created by db_select() and add a tag of "node_access". This will allow modules dealing with node access to ensure only nodes to which the user has access.."

Comment: If, however, you then need to load fields information, other then the `nid`, `title` or `status`, you will be performing another roundtrip to the database. E.g. a `node_load` for each found item, will cause *at least* 21 queries for an uncached set, if your query returns 20 nodes. Possibly a lot more, if you have modules that add their data to nodes on node_load.

Comment: @berkes I would use node_load_multiple() http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_load_multiple/7 for such a case.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to retrieve nodes of particular content type and want to display somewhere, obviously you can use the powerful module "VIEWS" by using which you can do all the magic.

Comment: Yes thanks i am aware of what view is, though it s definitely not the most efficient way to perform queries, just a more convenient one